# Hartman–Grobman theorem for a two-dimensional system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, dynamical-systems, smooth-manifolds

I want to find a diffeomorphism $G$ defined on some neighborhood of the origin with $G(0)=0$ such that $G$ transforms the linear system $\dot{x}=x$ to the nonlinear system $\dot{y}=y-y^2$. (These are one-dimensional systems).

Any comments or responses are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The diffeomorphism is
$$
y=\frac{x}{x-1}.
$$
Indeed,
$$
\dot y=\frac{\dot x(x-1)-x\dot x}{(x-1)^2}= \frac{x(x-1)-x^2}{(x-1)^2}=
\frac{x}{x-1}-\frac{x^2}{(x-1)^2}=y-y^2.
$$
This result can be observed by a comparison between the general solutions
$
x= Ce^t
$
and
$
y=\frac{Ce^t}{Ce^t-1}
$.

Comment: Thanks! I think the domain of this diffeomorphism is $(-\infty, 1)$.

Comment: @Arthur Yes, $(-\infty,1)\to (-\infty,1)$